# Custom ComboBox with Multi-line and Colored Items

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have been looking for a combo that looks or have similar features with this one in the image below. Is there any already available one, or can you direct me to how to make a custom one

[image: custom combo]

Comment: It's an owner-drawn `ComboBox`.

Comment: Use a `FlowLayoutPanel` and a custom `UserControl` to create the items to add to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an owner-drawn `ComboBox`.

For example you can:

- Set [`DrawMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `OwnerDrawFixed`
- Set `ItemHeight` property to a suitable height
- Handle [`DrawItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) event and draw items based on your required logic.

**Sample Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    this.comboBox1.ItemHeight = 40;
    var db = new TestDBEntities();
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = db.Products.ToList();
}
private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index > -1)
    {
        var name = ((Product)this.comboBox1.Items[e.Index]).Name;
        var id = ((Product)this.comboBox1.Items[e.Index]).Id; ;
        var price = ((Product)this.comboBox1.Items[e.Index]).Price; ;

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
        else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == DrawItemState.Focus)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.InactiveCaption, e.Bounds);
        else
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(name,
            new Font(this.comboBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
            Brushes.Blue,
            new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top,
                e.Bounds.Width, this.comboBox1.ItemHeight / 2));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Id:{0}", id),
            this.comboBox1.Font,
            Brushes.Red,
            new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top + this.comboBox1.ItemHeight / 2,
                e.Bounds.Width / 2, this.comboBox1.ItemHeight / 2));


        e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("Price:{0}", price),
            this.comboBox1.Font,
            Brushes.Red,
            new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + e.Bounds.Width / 2,
                e.Bounds.Top + this.comboBox1.ItemHeight / 2,
                e.Bounds.Width, this.comboBox1.ItemHeight / 2));
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help, but how do I draw the gradient selection on hover highlight in the combobox and the items list

Comment: You are welcome, you can use a solid brush or a gradient brush to fill a rectangle.

Comment: I also added some code to handle item state to let you draw highlighted item.

Comment: @Will The OP just doesn't have any idea about how to render a combo box. He asked *"Can you direct me to how to make a custom one?"* I think  the answer will be useful for the OP and future readers :) Is there another place for him to ask such question?

Comment: @Will Also downvoting an answer because you think the **question** is off-topic is unfair and strange. You can vote for close.

Comment: Your first comment is why I deleted my comment, I realized you were telling him how to create something rather than pointing him to a product, like the op is asking for.  Answering off topic questions only encourages them.  Please don't.  That's why I downvoted.  There are plenty of discussions about this kind of downvote on [meta], if you're interested in the reasonings behind this.

Comment: @Will Thank you for your response:) I believe when we think a question is off-topic we should vote the question to close and our idea about the the question should not affect answers and downvoting the answer is not the way we should go. ٌWhen you downvote my answer while you believe the question is off-topic, you deter me from answering a question because you think it's off-topic while I don't think so.  A downvote to an answer means the answer is incorrect or irrelevant or low quality. I don't think you have such idea about the answer :)