# ComboBox Text Align Vertically Center

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, .net-1.1

I created the custom combobox on .net framework 1.1, i can custom draw dropdown items,  but i can't set or draw the combobox text on Middle Left , combobox text always render top left , but i need text should be render on middle left.

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ComboBox))]
public class MenComboBox :ComboBox
{
    private Image _image = Image.FromFile("Expand.png");
    public MenComboBox()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.ItemHeight = 18;
        this.Font = new Font("Arial",12f,FontStyle.Regular);
    }       
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {

            if (!DesignMode)
            {
                if (e.Index > -1)
                {
                    int textHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font).Height;
                    Point textPos = new Point(e.Bounds.X + 4, e.Bounds.Y + ((this.ItemHeight - textHeight) / 2));
                    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.Bounds);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font,Brushes.White,textPos);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),e.Font,Brushes.Black,textPos);
                    }
                }
            }

    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
        {
            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), this.ClientRectangle);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X, this.ClientRectangle.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width - 1, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 1));
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(this.Width - 15, 3, 12, this.Height - 6);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), rect);
                g.DrawImage(this._image, this.Width - 16, (this.Height - 8) / 2);
                g.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: my Custom Combobox Appearance]

Comment: Remove try/catch and show what is the error? And note that catching all exceptions are senseless and is a strong sign you are doing wrong

Comment: The textbox portion has no option to get the text aligned to the center, custom draw doesn't fix it either.  Padding the text with spaces can be a somewhat silly workaround.  Meh, users are entirely used to the look+feel of comboboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an owner draw `ComboBox` the text of the `Edit` part of the control will always be shown at top left, regardless of the height of the `ItemHeight`.

To position the `Edit` part vertically in middle, you can find the `Edit` element using `GetComboBoxInfo` and then using `SetWindowPos` set a new position for it to stand vertically in middle of the `ComboBox`.

You need to reposition it when the control size changes. Also you need to fill the background of `ComboBox` with a Color.

[image]

Here is the code that I used:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        ItemHeight = 40;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
        public int Width { get { return Right - Left; } }
        public int Height { get { return Bottom - Top; } }
    }

    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, 
        int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);
        SetupEdit();
        Invalidate();
    }
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0xF)
        {
            using (var g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                var r = new Rectangle(2, 2,
                    ClientRectangle.Width - buttonWidth - 2,
                    ClientRectangle.Height - 4);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, r);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        SetupEdit();
    }
    private void SetupEdit()
    {
        var info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref info);
        SetWindowPos(info.hwndEdit, IntPtr.Zero, 3,
            (this.Height - Font.Height) / 2,
            ClientRectangle.Width - buttonWidth - 3,
            ClientRectangle.Height - Font.Height - 4,
            SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        e.DrawBackground();
        var txt = "";
        if (e.Index >= 0)
            txt = GetItemText(Items[e.Index]);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, Font, e.Bounds, 
            ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But will that actually show centered and editable text?

Comment: @TaW Yes, to make it less confusing, I changed the screenshot. In fact I change the position of the Edit control. I'm not painting it.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused. Especially as I wonder how OP could make the text appear top-left; it certainly doesn't do that here. Maybe a .Net .1.1 thing..?

Comment: @TaW Change the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and set `ItemHeight` to `40` for example, then you will see the edit part will always appear on top left.

Comment: Ah, yes, with sufficient care one can indeed shoot oneself in the foot. Itemheight shouldn't really be set imo since it interferes with the Font size. After setting it I had to go the desgner code to get rid of it again.. (Btw: Was that necessary or is there a trick to reset it to automatic?)

Comment: @TaW Imagine an owner draw combobox [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877290/3110834). In this case, the Item height should be set to a value more than the font height.

Comment: Yes, that is an excellent example. Otoh, when the user can enlarge the font keeping it automatic is much simpler.. And all the owner-drawing was just about the vertical alignment anyway. Hehe, we probably lost him anyway ;-)

Comment: @Reza , when i set Arial 18f  size , then Combobox text won't appear properly. https://ibb.co/kCR4p7

Comment: Using a larger `ItemHeight` solved the problem for me.

Comment: @reza But if increase  itemheight  then control is very big ,then its not looks good, so that i need text should be occupy the margin space also.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another fix for that, If I could find any, I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, below code doesn't answer the actual question about the Text portion; Hans got it right, as usual.

I keep the answer because I think it does a few things better than OP code..

[image]

```
    if (!DesignMode)
    {
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
           using (StringFormat fmt = new StringFormat() 
             { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
           {

            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.MenuHighlight, e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
                                        e.Font,SystemBrushes.HighlightText, e.Bounds, fmt);
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 
                                        e.Font, SystemBrushes.MenuText,e.Bounds, fmt);
            }
         }
      }
    }
```

Instead of calculating a centered position I use the `DrawString` overload that takes a target rectangle and add a `StringFormat` to center in both directions. `StringFormat` was available since .Net 1.1 and indeed is `IDisposable`, so we should dipose of each we create, best in a `using` clause..

Note that for drawing controls the use of `TextRenderer` is encouraged but only came with .Net 2.0.

Also note that I substituted the `Brushes` for `SystemBrushes`..

Also: My ComboBox doesn't place the text in its Text portion top-left but middle-left. Maybe the old .Net1.1 control is the culprit?

Comment: Believe it or not, StringFormat actually implements IDisposable.  Go figure.

Comment: Ok, I believe.. thanks for keeping track of my stuff ;-)

Comment: I don't understand why you say that this does not answer the OP question. Also, if you set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`, the text in the "editor" portion will be centered. So, there are also two possible ways of presenting the content. I think this is exactly what's been requested.

Comment: Well, while the DropDownList version is a good observation, (thanks for that!) the OP clearly shows an editable text field. Otoh it also shows non-centered dropdown but the code at least seems to try to center..