# How to center-align a selected Item in a ComboBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, alignment

I have a form with a ComboBox. I found the post: http://blog.michaelgillson.org/2010/05/18/left-right-center-where-do-you-align/ that helped me to centre-align all the items in the DropDown list. The problem is that the selected item (the item shown in the comboBox.Text property) remains left aligned.

How can I centre-align also the selected Item?
The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTextProperty
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> source = new List<string>() { "15", "63", "238", "1284", "13561" };
            comboBox1.DataSource = source;
            comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBox_DrawItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allow the text in the ComboBox to be center aligned.
    /// Change the DrawMode Property from Normal to either OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable.
    /// If DrawMode is not changed, the DrawItem event will NOT fire and the DrawItem event handler will not execute.
    /// For a DropDownStyle of DropDown, the selected item remains left aligned but the expanded dropped down list is centered.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox1 = sender as ComboBox; // By using sender, one method could handle multiple ComboBoxes.
        if (comboBox1 != null)
        {
            e.DrawBackground(); // Always draw the background.               
            if (e.Index >= 0) // If there are items to be drawn.
            {
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat(); // Set the string alignment.  Choices are Center, Near and Far.
                format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                // Set the Brush to ComboBox ForeColor to maintain any ComboBox color settings.
                // Assumes Brush is solid.
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(comboBox1.ForeColor);
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) // If drawing highlighted selection, change brush.
                {
                    brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                }
                e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), comboBox1.Font, brush, e.Bounds, format); // Draw the string.
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You also need to override the _Paint_ event to do that. I suggest that you create a new derived class from the `ComboBox` control and override both `OnPaint` and `OnDrawItem`.

Comment: Also [Center the text of a combobox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41303bd2-5d55-43c9-aa41-7869bdac79ca/center-the-text-of-a-combobox?forum=vbgeneral) should help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make the text horizontally centered, you need to do two things:

1. To center-align dropdown menu items, make the `ComboBox` owner-draw and draw the items yourself, center-aligned.
2. To center-align the text area of the control, find the `Edit` control of the `ComboBox` and set `ES_CENTER` style for it to make it center-aligned as well.

[image]

You may also be interested to this post: [ComboBox Text Align Vertically Center](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820008/3110834).

**Example**

To make the dropdown text align at center, you need to handle drawing of items yourself. To do so, set [`DrawMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `ComboBox` to `OwnerDrawFixed`. Then you can handle [`DrawItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event or override [`OnDrawItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.ondrawitem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

To set the alignment of text area to center, you need to find the [`Edit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control owned by `ComboBox`. To do so, you can use [`GetComboBoxInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method which returns a [`COMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-comboboxinfo?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). The next step is calling [`GetWindowLong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method to get styles of the edit control and then add [`ES_CENTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and then call [`SetWindowLong`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongw?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to set the new style.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    const int ES_LEFT = 0x0000;
    const int ES_CENTER = 0x0001;
    const int ES_RIGHT = 0x0002;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
        public int Width { get { return Right - Left; } }
        public int Height { get { return Bottom - Top; } }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetupEdit();
    }
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    private void SetupEdit()
    {
        var info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref info);
        var style = GetWindowLong(info.hwndEdit, GWL_STYLE);
        style |= 1;
        SetWindowLong(info.hwndEdit, GWL_STYLE, style);
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        e.DrawBackground();
        var txt = "";
        if (e.Index >= 0)
            txt = GetItemText(Items[e.Index]);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, Font, e.Bounds,
            ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
    }
}
```

Note: I put the whole logic inside a derived control called `MyComboBox` to make it more reusable and easier to apply, however, obviously you can do this without inheritance and just by relying on the events of an existing `ComboBox` control. You can also enhance the code a  bit by adding a `TextAlignment` property which allows setting the text alignment.

Comment: I put the whole logic inside a derived control called `MyComboBox` to make it more reusable and easier to apply, however, obviously you can do this without inheritance and just by relying on the events of an existing `ComboBox` control.

Comment: The supported/compatible functions should be `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr` (I also forgot to mention it and it just came to mind). I find this declaration working in all situations I tested it in: `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] internal static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);`. Same for `GetWindowLongPtr` (except `IntPtr dwNewLong`, of course). In 32 bit applications, these functions automatically fall-back to the previous version.