# How to have a multi-coloured items of a ListBox in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, listbox, listboxitem

I am developing a software in winforms, I am stuck in a step where I have

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.
```

and some sample data:

```
List <KeyValuePair<"S", "1200">>
List <KeyValuePair<"S", "1300">>
List <KeyValuePair<"L", "1400">>
```

I want to diplay the value of the key pair inside a ListBox, where based in the key of the pair the Item on the ListBox has a diffrent colour, for example if the Key is S, then the Item should be red and if the Key is L the Item should be blue.

Hope you could help me with this.

this is the code I did but it doesn't do what is expected:

```
        e.DrawBackground();
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Graphics x = e.Graphics;

        g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Olive), e.Bounds);
        x.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Aquamarine), e.Bounds);

        foreach (var workOrders in GetItac.FilterWorkOrders())
        {
            if (workOrders.Key == "S")
            {
                g.DrawString(workOrders.Value, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

            }
            else
            {
                x.DrawString(workOrders.Value, e.Font, new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), new PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));

            }

        }
```

Comment: This will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color it's also a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# : changing listbox row color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554609/c-sharp-changing-listbox-row-color)

Comment: those answers doesn't show tell me how to change the color based on the Key. Also I do not want to change the background color, I need to chnage the ForeColour of the item.

Comment: [Custom ComboBox with Multi-line and Colored Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877290/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to show customized results in a ListBox Control, you need to enable the custom painting of the `Items` in the list, setting the `ListBox` [DrawMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode) property to `OwnerDrawVariable`  or `OwnerDrawFixed` (the latter will set all Items to the same height).

**Note** → Here, I'm setting it to `OwnerDrawVariable`

The list `Items` painting needs to be performed in the [DrawItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem) event of the ListBox, using the [DrawItemEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawitemeventargs)'s Graphics object. This allow a correct refresh of the `Items` when the ListBox or Form need repainting.

1 - You don't have to *multiply* your Graphics object.
2 - The `foreach` loop is not needed either, because each Item will be painted when you create/modify the ListBox `Items` collection.

**Note** → I'm drawing the `Items` background the way you're showing in your code, but the visual result might be a bit weird (those colors don't blend well).

---

First, simulate the result of your `GetItac.FilterWorkOrders()` method, which will return a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, add those items `Value` to the list:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> workOrders;

workOrders = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("S", "1200" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("S", "1300"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("L", "1400")
};
//Select().ToList() extracts the Value string from the KeyValuePair elements
listBox1.DataSource = workOrders.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
```

You can also code it this way, if that method actually returns a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`:

```
workOrders = GetItac.FilterWorkOrders();
listBox1.DataSource = workOrders.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToList();
//Or
workOrders = GetItac.FilterWorkOrders();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(workOrders.Select(kv => kv.Value).ToArray());
```

When the ListBox `Items` collection is filled, the `DrawItem` event will be raised, to allow the painting of the `Items` content.
You may need to add the [MeasureItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.measureitem) event, to be sure to have a correct measure of each Item's height (mandatory, if you plan on modifying the ListBox Font.

For each item that is drawn, the text color is chosen testing the `Key` of the `KeyValuePair<string, string>`: if its value is `"S"`, the text color is set to `Color.Red`, the background color to `Color.Olive`. Otherwise they're set to `Color.Blue` and `Color.Aquamarine`.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var lbx = sender as ListBox;
    e.DrawBackground();
    Color textColor = (workOrders[e.Index].Key == "S") ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;
    Color backColor = (workOrders[e.Index].Key == "S") ? Color.Olive : Color.Aquamarine;

    using (var backBrush = new SolidBrush(backColor))
    using (var foreBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backBrush, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(workOrders[e.Index].Value, lbx.Font, foreBrush, 
                              e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
    }
}

private void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemHeight = (sender as ListBox).Font.Height;
}
```

Comment: @Omar AlMadani  Well, I'm glad it was helpful :)