# Bold/recolor selected item of Listbox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, colors, listbox, selecteditem, bold

I'm new on vb.net and visual studio, i have the feeling i will be downvoted to death.

I want each time i selected an item from my listbox, the selected item's text to become bold or change it's color... (like a readed/unreaded feature)

The only way is to manually draw my listbox? On my mind it should be an easier way, like with SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: The ListView control makes this particular task infinitely easier to accomplish. Have you considered/tried using that control instead?

Comment: You would need to owner-draw the items in the `ListBox` to accomplish that. It's not actually that hard, although it may be daunting to a beginner. Do some research on that topic, have a go and then, if you encounter issues, we can help you with those specifically.

Comment: "The only way is to manually draw my listbox?". Yes, you must owner-draw the items. "On my mind it should be an easier way, like with SelectedIndexChanged event". And what exactly would you do in the event handler?  There's no type that represents the items so there's nothing for you to bold. It's done by owner-drawing and, for something this basic, it's not really especially difficult.

Comment: could you supply me with an example code how owner-drawing works?

Comment: Posted a few days ago: [Changing color, highlight, background size of a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715075/changing-color-highlight-background-size-of-a-listbox/50731483#50731483). But, as already suggested, you should also consider the ListView control for this. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50759508/how-to-have-a-multi-coloured-items-of-a-listbox-in-winforms?answertab=active#tab-top) is written in C#, but there's a description that you might find useful.

Comment: I don't think you cant do that with a listbox. A listbox basically has the same capabilities as a regular textbox, at least as far as text styling goes. The alternative would probably be a listview as a richtextbox would be to a textbox.