# How to Format Listbox or padding

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, formatting

[image]

When I click my products from left side of the form, then I get them on `ListBox` padded name with price.
But because every product name name length is different then the price lies ugly formatting, it is not straight way as you see in my image left side.
I want them like on the right side if you see on my attached image.
My code in List box Format event is as following but not working Formatting as I want. Please Help!

```
private void ListOfPaidProducts_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    string currentProductName = ((Product)e.ListItem).Description;
    string currentPrice = String.Format("{0}", ((Product)e.ListItem).Price); // I tried even with {0,20}....

    string currentProductNamePadded = currentProductName.PadRight(30);

    e.Value = currentProductNamePadded + currentPrice + "$";
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `DataGridView` instead. While I advise you to use `DataGridView`, just for information, without using a mono-spaced font you cannot achieve a clean and tidy multi-column formatting for `ListBox`, unless you decide to do custom painting, something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877290/3110834).

Comment: You could use the [UseCustomTabOffsets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usecustomtaboffsets) feature of the `ListBox`, or, better, use a ListView or a DataGridView, as already suggested. Since the text length will probably change, you may want to avoid hard-coded values or constantly measuring the text, so a different control is quite the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use ListView instead of ListBox.

For example, for the data

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>
{
   new Product{Description = "abc efg", Price= 123},
   new Product{Description = "abc efg hijk 12 1212 12", Price= 23},
   new Product{Description = "abc", Price= 343},
   new Product{Description = "abc efg", Price= 22}
};
```

You can configure the ListView as following.

Set ListView's view as Detail to show multiple columns

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Next Add two columns, for display discription and Price.

```
listView1.Columns.Add("Description");
listView1.Columns.Add("Price");
```

Now you can add the items to the ListView as follows.

```
foreach(var items in list)
{
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
   lvi.Text = items.Description;
   lvi.SubItems.Add($"{items.Price} $");
   listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Finally, you can ensure the Columns resize themselves to max size of contents by using AutoReizeColumn Method.

```
listView1.AutoResizeColumn(0, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
listView1.AutoResizeColumn(1, ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

You might be also interested in the FullRowSelect property of ListView which enables selection of full row, rather than column on mouse click on row.

```
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use fonts which allocate same space for each character, like "Courier New", you can prep you object like

```
public class DisplayProduct // create a little decorator
{
     public DisplayProduct(Product prod, int pad)
     {
         Display = prod.Name.PadRight(pad) + prod.Price;
     }

     private Product Prod {get; set;}

     // if you plan to use Product properties, you can change scope and do
     // ((ProductDisplay)list.SelectedItem).Prod.Price
     public int Id {get{return Prod.Id;}}  

     public string Name {get{return Prod.Name;}} 

     public string Display {get; private set;} 

}

List<Product> products = GetList(...);
int maxLen = products.Max(p => p.Name.Length) + 5;
var diplayList = products.Select(p => new DisplayProduct(p, maxLen));

myListBox.DisplayMember = "Display";
myListBox.ValueMember = "Id";    
myListBox.DataSource = diplayList;
```

But you could use grid or even a `ListView` for displaying structure data. Another thing you can do  - custom item draw in `ListBox`. But I don't think it worth the exercise.

Comment: Those are called **monospaced fonts**, if you want to search for a list to see what other options you've got.

Comment: @Idle_Mind My answer is strictly related to OPs wishes. Of course, there are many options.