# Can c# windows form list view have item template with 2 rows and 2 columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a list of items that is constantly updated from live readings, the newest items should be added on the top of the list.

is it possible to have an item template for the list view with 2 rows and 2 column for each item. (like attached photo).

I searched online i could not find a solution.

my second approach was to create Main Panel and append Panels to it sub panels to it containing the labels.I am only able to add the items in the bottom of the Main panel since i can calculate the location of the last added item.

```
        Panel pan = new Panel();
        pan.Name = "panel" + counter;
        pan.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.AutoSize = true;
        label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        label1.Name = "label" + counter;
        label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label1.TabIndex = 1;
        label1.Text = "label" + counter;

        Label label2 = new Label();
        label2.AutoSize = true;
        label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 20);
        label2.Name = "label2" + counter;
        label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label2.TabIndex = 2;
        label2.Text = "label2" + counter;

        Label label3 = new Label();
        label3.AutoSize = true;
        label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 0);
        label3.Name = "label3" + counter;
        label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label3.TabIndex = 3;
        label3.Text = "label3" + counter;

        Label label4 = new Label();
        label4.AutoSize = true;
        label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 20);
        label4.Name = "label4" + counter; ;
        label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        label4.TabIndex = 4;
        label4.Text = "label4" + counter;

        pan.Location = new Point(0, counter * 50);
        pan.Size = new Size(100, 50); 
        pan.Controls.Add(label1);
        pan.Controls.Add(label2);
        pan.Controls.Add(label3);
        pan.Controls.Add(label4);

        MainPanel.Controls.Add(pan);
        counter++;
```

[image: Example]

Thanks

Comment: you could use a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=netframework-4.8) and set the `FlowDirection` to `BottomUp`. This way you don't even need to calculate any locations of the items. They will be added automatically to the correct positions inside the panel

Comment: It's quite similar to an owner draw list box. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877290/3110834) of a `ComboBox` like what you aksed, the `ListBox` is quite similar. [`DataRepeater` or stacked user controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32759588/3110834) are also option.

Comment: One of the method will be creating a `UserControl` and pass the data to the `UserControl` and render it in the `ListView`. So you will have complete flexibility on the Item design and rendering.

Comment: I created a UserControl and added it to flowlayout panel with buttomUp direction and it solved the case, thank you guys for the help